# HTML Table in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I have a dataset which looks like that:

```
dict = {
'columns': ['one', 'two', 'three'],
'headers': ['header1', 'header2', 'header3', 'header4'],
'data': [
    ['111', '222', '333'],
    ['111', '222', '333'],
    ['111', '222', '333'],
    ['111', '222', '333']
]}
```

How I can get this exact table, using HTML and Django:

[image: Needed table]

Please, provide the example of the code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We love questions here, but this is more of a "can you do the work for me" kind of question, which isn't going to get answered. If you're having trouble accomplishing this, show what you have, show where you're stuck. Don't just expect the community to do the work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this. Now before constructing the table we need to make a little change in the data, ie just attach the header items to data items,  prepend them to each item of data in the django view itself, resulting in something like this:

```
dict = {
'columns': ['one', 'two', 'three'],
'data': [
['header1', '111', '222', '333'],
['header2', '111', '222', '333'],
['header3', '111', '222', '333'],
['header4', '111', '222', '333']
]}
```

HTML code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
{% for each in dict.columns %}
        <th>{{ each }}</th>
{% endfor %}           
    </tr>
{% for each in dict.data %}
<tr>
{% for item in each %}
 <td>{{ item }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

```
{% endfor %}</table>
```